# Ionic content not scrolling after clicking side menu

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a side menu and ion view with ion content.
The login page is working fine and scrolling properly, also it gets through the landing page. 
First time landing page is scrolling properly. 
But when i am clicking the side menu and going to someother page, the scrolling to bottom and up is not happening.

**menu.html**

```
<ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="navBar" align-title="left"></ion-nav-bar>
          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-stable ion-navicon" style="color: #fff" ng-click="toggleLeft()">
            </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
         <ion-side-menu side="left">
         <ion-header-bar class="navBar" align-title="left">
         <h1 class="title">Menu List</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content class="menuList">
          <div class="list" >..
          </div>
          </ion-content>
                </ion-side-menu>
          </ion-side-menus>
```

**index.html**

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**landing.html**

```
<ion-view title="some title">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="parentDiv">
            </div>
              </ion-content>
              </ion-view >
```

Is there any issue with my code structure or any flaw in ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including ion-scroll, inside ion-side-menus.

```
<ion-scroll  direction="y">

</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Thanks uksz. ion scroll helped me.